How to change body color only for one body instance
I have an Angular project and in my app.component.html I have such component structure:
<nav class="left-menu-plus-body">
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  <header class="header-plus-body">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div class="main-container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </header>
</nav>
<app-footer></app-footer>


Also, I have a body CSS property:
body {
  background: linear-gradient(90.00deg, rgb(146, 133, 255), rgb(158, 192, 252) 100%);
}

Also I have any other pages which are included instead of router-outlet. Example:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Subject tasks</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--code here-->
</body>

</html>

As in all of my pages there is a body tag I have a background color for whole website and for the body:

I need to have only one gradient for whole page and not doubling it

You can target a specific element with a class.
<body class="mainBody">

.mainBody {
  background: linear-gradient(90.00deg, rgb(146, 133, 255), rgb(158, 192, 252) 100%);
}

Though you shouldn't be using body tags for multiple child elements anyway. There should be one body class as a child of your html tag.

Where should I use this targeting? in the page that is instead of router-outlet? Or in the app.component.html?
When I do first option. the background is set only for router-outlet part and I need to have the background for whole page but only once.

please note that the selector would be .mainBody, not mainBody as its a class selector

use it in styles.css
